# Screen flickering on Ubuntu 16.4 while inactivity

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, display, screen

I am a total Linux newbie and just installed Ubuntu 16.04 Unity a few days ago as a second OS besides Windows 10. Unfortunately it seems there is something wrong with the screen.

Whenever there is no activity like using the keyboard or touchpad, the whole screen is flickering evenly. As soon as I restart doing stuff it stops. It is not a real screen artifact more like a slight flickering but it is extremely annoying to look at permanently.

My laptop is an Asus UX303LA with an Intel Core i5 Haswell ULT, an Intel HD Graphics 4400 and a SSD drive.

I already reinstalled and updated the Intel Graphics driver and implemented the improvements I found on the [Community Wiki of Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook).
Additionally I tried various fixes which I found here in the forum on similiar problems with flickering screens. Yesterday I reinstalled the whole OS. Unfortunately none of this worked. Though it doesn't seem to be a hardware problem as the flickering doesn't appear on windows 10.

I would be very glad if anyone had an idea of what the problem could be and would help me out. Also, please excuse me in case I did not mention all relevant information, this is my first post here.

Thank you guys in advance,
Jannik

Comment: Can confirm the same issue on a Thinkpad E540 with intel/nvidia card. Symptoms persist over all the intel/nvidia/nouveau drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution and I thought I share it in case somebody is experiencing the same issue. I downgraded the kernel to v3.19 and now everything seem to work fine. Still have no idea what the actual problem was though.

Comment: Tried 4.7, 4.8 and 4.9, they have the issue.
Screen is stable when on 4.4.38.